# Xcode stopped working on device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Very new to xcode, app is working great in sim. But device is throwing error. Using Xcode 6.4, IOS 8.4.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Pretty sure this button is my problem...

```
 @IBAction func SubmitBtn(Sender: AnyObject) {
        var url: NSString = "http://localhost:8888/databaseTest.php?x=\(textFromFirstName)&y=\(textFromLastName)&z=\(textFromCity)"
        var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url as String)!)
        var result = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(result)
    }
```

This is the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

* thread #1: tid = 0xf7a6, 0x00327164 libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> () + 64, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
  * frame #0: 0x00327164 libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> () + 64
    frame #1: 0x000c4acc PlayerTrackingV3`PlayerTrackingV3.VerifyViewController.SubmitBtn (Sender=AnyObject at 0x00234020, self=0x14de20a0)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 1584 at VerifyViewController.swift:66
    frame #2: 0x000c4c24 PlayerTrackingV3`@objc PlayerTrackingV3.VerifyViewController.SubmitBtn (PlayerTrackingV3.VerifyViewController)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 104 at VerifyViewController.swift:0
    frame #3: 0x293e782a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
    frame #4: 0x293e77d0 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
    frame #5: 0x293d2374 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 584
    frame #6: 0x293e7210 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
    frame #7: 0x293e6ee2 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
    frame #8: 0x293e07f0 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 540
    frame #9: 0x293b69b4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
    frame #10: 0x2962d0fe UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14538
    frame #11: 0x293b53b6 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1350
    frame #12: 0x25d1b00e CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    frame #13: 0x25d1a422 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 222
    frame #14: 0x25d18aa0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 768
    frame #15: 0x25c646d0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #16: 0x25c644e2 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #17: 0x2d6021a8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 136
    frame #18: 0x29416444 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
    frame #19: 0x000d24fc PlayerTrackingV3`main + 196 at AppDelegate.swift:12
```

Completely clueless as to why it works in sim, and was working fine on device until just recently. And there has been no changes in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
var result = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Your `data` is nil, and saying `data!` you are unwrapping an optional that is nil, that it's not possible and it throws an Exception.

Please verify your `var data` if `contentsOfURL:` it's getting the right content.

Comment: The url is getting all the content. I don't understand how it post to database fine with no errors in sim but device is throwing this error. It seems like this error would make the sim error out also.

Comment: Now I see it. You are trying to access localhost on your device, its not possible. Localhost well... works only on your local machine. Thats why only works on simulator (because it's using a shared connection with your mac).

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was a stupid mistake....After putting everything on same network, and using ip address in place of localhost, everything seems to be working again. I was under the assumption if device was plugged into machine and app was executed through Xcode, that device  would act as sim.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I helped. And the device never uses shared connection with your Mac, it's always using his own connection.